# Physics and Nozick's explanatory self-subsumption

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-science, metaphysics, reference-request, physics

What happened with [Nozick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Nozick)'s idea of the self-subsuming explanation *after* his [*Philosophical Explanations*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophical_Explanations)?

In particular *and actually only*, I'm interested to learn about published attempts to use or debunk specifically this notion in the search for the [final theory of physics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_everything).

Comment: Gugg, you usually bring us interesting references. Out of curiosity I read the chapter "Why is there something rather than nothing" in the book of Nozik. It reminded me of the writings of Heidegger. Plain of nonsense. The response to nonsense like Heidegger's "The Nothing nothings" is the classic text "The Elimination of Metaphysics Through Logical Analysis of Language" by Rudolf Carnap. Frequently there is arbitrary closure of questions in this site. Often only one person, or 2, and not a reasonable minimum of people in the community, decides to close questions.I am disheartened to write here